# How to add error message with jQuery Validator

Tags: jquery, html, css

I got my "contact me" form working with the validation as I want but I can't figure out how to show the error messages. I've tried to read in the documentation but I just don't understand how to use the `errorPlacement` function. Can someone please show me an example on how to do it with the code I got?

```
<fieldset>
    <input placeholder="Ditt navn" name="contact_name"  id="contact_name" class="contact_input" type="text"  tabindex="1" required autofocus>
</fieldset>
<fieldset>
    <input placeholder="Din email adresse" name="contact_mail" id="contact_mail"  class="contact_input"  type="email" tabindex="2" required>
</fieldset>
<fieldset>
    <input placeholder="Firma navn (valgfri)" name="contact_firmname" id="contact_firmname"  class="contact_input" type="text" tabindex="3">
</fieldset>


$(document).ready(function(){
    $('body').on('keyup','#contact_me',function(){
      $('#contact_me').validate({
        rules: {
          contact_name: {
            required: true,
            remote: location.protocol + '//' + location.host+'/ajax_contact.php'
          },
          contact_mail: {
            required: true,
            remote: location.protocol + '//' + location.host+'/ajax_contact.php'
          },
          contact_firmname: {
          },
        },
        errorPlacement: function(){
            return false;
        },
        submitHandler: function (form) {
          return false;
        }
     });
   });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't get stucked on documentation if you can't figure out how to do something. Instead look for an example, wich is often 1000 times clearer.

This article shows a testeable example of what you are trying to reproduce in your code: https://www.webcodegeeks.com/javascript/jquery/jquery-errorplacement-example/